# How to find an element B that exists below another element A

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Say in a webpage:

```
Element A     #A is here
...           #Some code
Element B     #B is here
```

A and B don't have parent child relationship, but they have the same locator.

No elements exist between A and B that have the same locator.

How do I locate B (There are other elements below B that also have the same locator), given that I have located A.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the part of the HTML where Element A and Element B are present, without it no one can provide a efficient way to locate elements.

having said, when you have multiple elements having the same locator and if you know the order when they are retrieved by the driver, you can use the find_elements method

```
elements = find_elements_by_css(<your_locator_strategy_>)
```

assuming you have used css, this will return a list and lets say Element B is the second item, you can do

```
elements[1].click()
```

assuming you want to click on the element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Your method seems to be: First identify all the elements, then click them one by one.

I wonder if there is a way to: Identify the first element, then click it. Afterwards, identify the next element, click it. etc. etc.
(Since the website I'm working on seems to be dynamic. If I use the first method, it would return an unclickable exception)